# How do I access the ElementRef inside shadow-dom when using NG2 Native View Encapsulation

Tags: angular

I have the [following plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CcbyJIuoZWZlUFLbyjzd?p=preview)

The problem I am having is when I turn on native view encapsulation I can no longer access the internal DOM (by design). My question is, does Angular 2 provide a way to access the DOM INSIDE the shadow dom from the component.

```
// Shows 1  
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
// Shows 0
// platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {defaultEncapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing to do with Angular2. You can use `shadowRoot` property to search elements inside of Shadow DOM.

```
const shadowRoot: DocumentFragment = this.element.nativeElement.shadowRoot;
this.count = shadowRoot.children.length;
```

Or use `ViewChild/ViewChildren` `ContentChild/ContentChildren` to get reference to `ElementRef`

Comment: Using @ViewChild seems to work thanks https://plnkr.co/edit/4XIjpQCAHnRr30bt0pHN?p=preview. Now lets see if I can use the local IDs while using pug :-)